# How to make script wait for Nautilus to exit

Tags: scripts, nautilus

I have a script that will extract files for examining to a temporary folder then call nautilus.

I'm trying to make the script wait for Nautilus to exit, then remove the temporary folder.  However, the folder is removed instantly after Nautilus is called.

I understand that Nautilus is a sub-window of Gnome which is controlling the Desktop.  However, I'm trying to figure out a way to call a new instance of Nautilus or workaround.

**The Script:**

```
#/bin/bash

tempdir=$(mktemp -d)

unzip ~/document.odt -d $tempdir
nautilus $tempdir

# waitfor nautilus to exit
# workaround 
zenity --info --title="Find Icons" --text="Click OK to exit" 2>/dev/null

rm -r $tempdir
```

Currently I'm using **Zenity** as a workaround to make the script wait by giving the user a prompt.  I'm trying to remove this extra step and have the script recognize the Nautilus window had closed, then automatically finish.

Comment: Nautilus is unlikely to quit, since the desktop is a nautilus window. What you need is a process that waits for nautilus to have no *normal* window (other than type: `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP`). You will need `wmctrl` and `xprop` to find out. (Please mention if you manage). Not sure though, do you mean a specifically named window, or any window at all?

Comment: Thanks! I'll study the how to implement what you described.  I don't understand the "Please mention if you manage" part.

Comment: ^ That is: just mention if you need any help :)

Comment: Thanks!  I'm sure I can figure it out.  You've provided what I consider the most important, and that, there isn't a way except for a programmable workaround.  If you could provide an example, I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keeping track of the `PID` and killing it from the shellscript works for me in a live system of Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS with the Xenial kernel and also in an up to date installed system with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (and the Xenial kernel).

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting Nautilus"

nautilus --no-desktop ~/Downloads & pid=$!

echo "pid=$pid"
ps -A|grep "$pid"

read -p "Press Enter when you are ready to kill the Nautilus window"

kill "$pid"
sync
echo "Checking that the process is gone"
ps -A|grep "$pid"
```

Edit:

It works, when killed like this, but when closed with the <kbd>x</kbd> control button, the process is still alive, which is a problem with Nautilus.

But if you use Thunar instead of Nautilus, the process will be killed, when the window is closed with the <kbd>x</kbd> button. So I suggest to switch file browser for this task,

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting Thunar"

thunar ~/Downloads

echo "Checking that the process is gone"
ps -A|grep "thunar"
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround.  It's similar to one of my implementations using the processID of `nautilaus $tempdir -n --no-default-window --no-desktop &` which will eventually return, but not immediately.  I'll add it to my question for more details of how far I have gotten.  There might not be a way to actually recognize the window has closed.  But if it is, I'm hoping to save the extra steps of going back to the script.  Currently, I'm trying to use tools such as provided by Jacob Vlijm to verify when the window has closed.

Comment: @L.D.James, It seems to me, that killing the `PID` will close the Nautilus window. The absence of the process can be checked via `ps -A` in your shellscript. Is it different for you? Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

Comment: With the xenial or zesty kernel?

Comment: It's stock: `Ubuntu 4.4.0-97.120-generic 4.4.87`.  I believe the default for the latest update/upgrade.

Comment: It is the same kernel as I use. I think Nautilus windows should be managed in the same way for us. So I think you should be able to control what to do before and after killing the nautilus window via the `PID`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67137/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-sudodus).

Comment: Although I upvoted this didn't work for me and I had to use this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/546241/best-way-to-check-if-nautilus-file-manager-is-running